# Return Multiple Row Matches not displayed: google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this code below and for some reason I am not able to retrieve the multiple rows that match the value. I only get one row result.

Sheet1-Check - Two columns only

- ColumnA - Account Name to check
- ColumnB - Status

Loop through column A, find all Row Matches. When it's done, mark column B with "Done", then continue with the next row value

Sheet2-Log (To display output)

- Currently, it only logs 1 matching row ---> ideal result should find all & display all  multiple Row Matches
- If there is different account name, ideal result should find all & log the result at the end of the last row.

Would be possible to add another check to see if the value also exists in another sheet (checking two different sheets)?

```
/* Details */
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
```

Perhaps I might have missed something. Would someone be able to check and let me know what is wrong and how I can fix it?

*Updated Code*

```
 function getMultipleRowsMatch() {
    
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXX');
      /* What value to search */
      var sheet1 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1-Check);
      var find1_Values = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues(); 
    
      var logValues = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2-Log');
logValues.getRange('A2:L').clear();
    
      /* Details */
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
      var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
    
      for (var i = 0; i < find1_Values.length; i++) {
        var findAccount = find1_Values[i][0];
        var findStatus = find1_Values[i][1];
    
        if (findStatus == "Done" || findAccount == "") { continue; }
        else {
           var textSearch = sheetData.createTextFinder(findAccount).findAll();
    
           var searchRows = [];
    
          if (textSearch.length > 0) {
         /* Retrieve row data values */
             for (var j = 0; j < textSearch.length; j++) {
              var row = textSearch[j].getRow();
              var rowLastColumn = sheetData.getLastColumn();
              var rowValues = sheetData.getRange(row, 14, 1, rowLastColumn).getValues();
    
              //searchRows.push(rowValues);
      logValues.getRange(logValues.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowValues.length, rowValues[0].length).setValues(rowValues);
            }
          }
        }
      logValues.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue("Done");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Two things: the second loop also has 'i'as the variable, so it will not continue to run the first loop. You should change the name of the second one. And about that live that says "logValues.getRange(i + 2, 2). setValues....", Shouldn't it be inside the loop? it appears to be outside

Comment: @Martín, Thank you for catching that. I also noticed that my 1st loop was incorrect and I fixed it. It is now working as expected. I updated the code I posted above. Thanks!

Comment: I consider this could be added as an answer instead of a comment, so it can be easily referenced for other users in the community.

Comment: @MilagroSosa I posted the updated code as an answer yesterday and it looks like it was not displayed/formatted correctly, I just edited it and reposted it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Incase others might find this helpful.

```
function getMultipleRowsMatch() {
        
          var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXX');
          /* What value to search */
          var sheet1 = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1-Check);
          var find1_Values = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues(); 
        
          var logValues = s.getSheetByName('Sheet2-Log');
    logValues.getRange('A2:L').clear();
        
          /* Details */
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX');
          var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
        
          for (var i = 0; i < find1_Values.length; i++) {
            var findAccount = find1_Values[i][0];
            var findStatus = find1_Values[i][1];
        
            if (findStatus == "Done" || findAccount == "") { continue; }
            else {
               var textSearch = sheetData.createTextFinder(findAccount).findAll();
        
               var searchRows = [];
        
              if (textSearch.length > 0) {
             /* Retrieve row data values */
                 for (var j = 0; j < textSearch.length; j++) {
                  var row = textSearch[j].getRow();
                  var rowLastColumn = sheetData.getLastColumn();
                  var rowValues = sheetData.getRange(row, 14, 1, rowLastColumn).getValues();
        
          logValues.getRange(logValues.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowValues.length, rowValues[0].length).setValues(rowValues);
                }
              }
            }
          logValues.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue("Done");
          }
        }
```